# My Job does no longer starts when I use spring.batch.job.names

Tags: spring-batch

I have a number of jobs configured run at different occasions. There are jobs that are started from a rest endpoint and the main one that should start immediately. Here is the configuration:

```
    spring:
      config:
          activate:
          on-profile: dev
      batch:
      job:
             enabled: true
             names: startMigrationJob
      jdbc:
             initialize-schema: always
      datasource:
            schema: schema-postgresql.sql
            auto-commit: true
```

The job does not run anymore and there is no error just the bootRun prompt. I don't know how the job used to run and now with the configuration the job no longer runs. Please help provide why this is the case

Comment: Is that the actual indentation of the yaml? Currently, `batch` and `job` are on the same level. So, you're not setting `spring.batch.job.names` but `spring.job.names`.

Comment: No, it's correctly indented. It was hard. to copy it from the ide. and format it properly. I wanted to display the values that are applied to the configuration

Answer (score 0):

The batch job does run according to the scheduled cron job. I created a cron job that runs every 10 minutes to ensure it ran, and it did. It seems the behaviour is different when you do not specify a job to run.